# How to detect node(peer) in the network

Tags: go-ethereum, peers

Hi I need check is certain node is currently connected to the network(or current peer).
How I can do it, and how to identificate node by ip address or how?

P.S. via api or (sorry not go-geth client) nodejs or via curl query.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if i've understood your need but you can use `admin.peer` to get details about the peers connected to your node.

```
admin.peers
[{
  ID: 'a4de274d3a159e10c2c9a68c326511236381b84c9ec52e72ad732eb0b2b1a2277938f78593cdbe734e6002bf23114d434a085d260514ab336d4acdc312db671b',
  Name: 'Geth/v0.9.14/linux/go1.4.2',
  Caps: 'eth/60',
  RemoteAddress: '5.9.150.40:30301',
  LocalAddress: '192.168.0.28:39219'
}, {
  ID: 'a979fb575495b8d6db44f750317d0f4622bf4c2aa3365d6af7c284339968eef29b69ad0dce72a4d8db5ebb4968de0e3bec910127f134779fbcb0cb6d3331163c',
  Name: 'Geth/v0.9.15/linux/go1.4.2',
  Caps: 'eth/60',
  RemoteAddress: '52.16.188.185:30303',
  LocalAddress: '192.168.0.28:50995'
}, {
  ID: 'f6ba1f1d9241d48138136ccf5baa6c2c8b008435a1c2bd009ca52fb8edbbc991eba36376beaee9d45f16d5dcbf2ed0bc23006c505d57ffcf70921bd94aa7a172',
  Name: 'pyethapp_dd52/v0.9.13/linux2/py2.7.9',
  Caps: 'eth/60, p2p/3',
  RemoteAddress: '144.76.62.101:30303',
  LocalAddress: '192.168.0.28:40454'
}, {
  ID: 'f4642fa65af50cfdea8fa7414a5def7bb7991478b768e296f5e4a54e8b995de102e0ceae2e826f293c481b5325f89be6d207b003382e18a8ecba66fbaf6416c0',
  Name: '++eth/Zeppelin/Rascal/v0.9.14/Release/Darwin/clang/int',
  Caps: 'eth/60, shh/2',
  RemoteAddress: '129.16.191.64:30303',
  LocalAddress: '192.168.0.28:39705'
} ]
```

you can find more details in the official documentation:
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Connecting-to-the-network#checking-connectivity

Comment: I need this info but need call this data via web3 interface or some api (even curl I dont care)) )

Comment: it doesn't look like you can get this info from web3js (https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-net.html) or ethersjs (https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-providers.html#id2)

Comment: @Josh, yes I was needed extande the standart web3js library via add access to the admin object